# Problems building summarize gem on Ruby and Win32

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

I have a working Ruby 1.8.7 installation on Windows XP using the installer provided at http://rubyinstaller.org/, along with the Ruby Dev Kit also found there. Both are working, to the extent I can install gems, including some with native extensions.

I'm trying to use the summarize gem from http://rubygems.org/gems/summarize. When I run `gem install summarize`, it fails to build the native extensions and I get this error:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...  
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...  
ERROR:  Error installing summarize:  
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb

creating Makefile

make

gcc -I. -I/C/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32 -I/C/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mi
ngw32 -I.   -g -O2 -DFD_SETSIZE=256    -c article.c
In file included from article.c:25:0:
libots.h:24:18: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

make: *** [article.o] Error 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/summarize-1
.0.3 for inspection.

Results logged to C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/summarize-1.0.3/ext/summariz
e/gem_make.out
```

I don't know what to do to correct this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It look like you need to install [Glib development package](http://www.gtk.org/download-windows.html))

Comment: Thanks, Pablo. I think that's it, too. The thing that's throwing me is how to get glib installed and working with the Mingw32 tools provided by the Ruby devkit. My home platform is OS X, and I'm trying to help a Windows developer get all this going.

Comment: Unpack it some place in your friend's hard drive like C:\glib and pass the appropiate flags to the compiler (-I/C/glib/include) and linker (-L/C/glib/lib), this is usually done with `gem install summarize -- -I... -L...` or tweaking extconf.rb